# SQL Server 2012 - Sliding Functions using OVER

Tags: sql-server-2012

Say I have the following schema:

```
-- Create the dbo.Transaction table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] (
    [TransactionId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [AccountId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] DateTime2(7) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] decimal(9,3) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction] PRIMARY KEY ([TransactionId])
);
```

And the following query:

```
Select
    AccountId,
    TransactionDate,
    Amount,
    AverageAmount       = Avg(Amount)   Over (Partition By AccountId Order By TransactionDate ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
    TransactionCount    = Count(Amount) Over (Partition By AccountId Order By TransactionDate ROWS 2 PRECEDING),
    MinimumAmount       = Min(Amount)   Over (Partition By AccountId Order By TransactionDate ROWS 2 PRECEDING),
    MaximumAmount       = Max(Amount)   Over (Partition By AccountId Order By TransactionDate ROWS 2 PRECEDING),
    SumAmount           = Sum(Amount)   Over (Partition By AccountId Order By TransactionDate ROWS 2 PRECEDING)
From dbo.[Transaction]
Order By AccountId, TransactionDate
```

How would I perform this query if it were contained in a UDF or stored proc, and the sliding interval (2 in this example) wasn't known until runtime, as passed as a parameter to the UDF / stored proc? It seems SQL 2012 doesn't permit the use of a variable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, SQL Server only supports integer literals for PRECEDING and FOLLOWING in OVER clauses.

There are two options available to you:  dynamic sql and re-writing the query to not use PRECEDING

Dynamic sql is the simpliest, but I'd be careful about putting it in a UDF.

```
set @sql = N'Select AccountId, ... ROWS ' 
          + cast(@sz as varchar(10)) + N' PRECEDING) ...'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

However window functions are just fancy syntax.  You can re-write the query without them:

```
DECLARE @sz INT
SET @sz = 2

;
WITH    q AS ( SELECT   AccountId ,
                        TransactionDate ,
                        Amount ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId 
                                            ORDER BY TransactionDate ) rw
               FROM     [Transaction]
             )
    SELECT  accountID ,
            TransactionDate ,
            Amount ,
            ( SELECT    AVG(q1.Amount) FROM  q q1
              WHERE     q1.accountid = q.accountid
                        AND q1.rw BETWEEN q.rw - @sz AND q.rw
            ) AverageAmount,
            ( SELECT    COUNT(q1.Amount) FROM  q q1
              WHERE     q1.accountid = q.accountid
                        AND q1.rw BETWEEN q.rw - @sz AND q.rw
            ) TransactionAmount
            -- etc.
            FROM q
            ORDER BY AccountID, TransactionDate
```

Here is another way to re-write the query as well:

```
DECLARE @sz INT
SET @sz = 2;
WITH    q AS ( SELECT   AccountId ,
                        TransactionDate ,
                        Amount ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId 
                                            ORDER BY TransactionDate ) rw
               FROM     [Transaction]
             )
    SELECT  q.accountID ,
            q.TransactionDate ,
            q.Amount ,
            AVG(q1.Amount) AverageAmount ,
            COUNT(q1.Amount) TransactionAmount ,
            MAX(q1.Amount) MaxAmount ,
            MIN(q1.Amount) MinAmount
                -- etc.
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN q q1 ON q1.accountid = q.accountid
                               AND q1.rw BETWEEN q.rw - @sz AND q.rw
    GROUP BY q.accountid ,
            q.transactiondate ,
            q.amount
```

Comment: Clever workaround but calling the window functions for "fancy syntax" is a bit unfair. With windows functions the query uses a `windows spool` to do the job of the moving window and since the over clause is identical for all aggregates there will be only one table scan (or index scan if you have a covering index). You workaround will have 6 table/index scans. Huge difference.

Comment: My point with referring to PRECEDING as fancy syntax is that it is possible to write a logically equivalent query without using the syntax.  I also added an additional way to re-write the query to reduce the number of scans.  Yes, Sql may give a better physical plan when using PRECEDING, but logically the queries are the same.

Comment: Good workaround, but painful still because of the additional overhead. I wonder if this will ever be possible with a variable window specification... probably not. But in certain cases, e.g. year-to-date calculations, such a sliding window specification would be super welcome.